# Combine csr with PreSave into one file for New and Edit forms

Tags: custom-form, client-side-rendering

I'm trying to combine all the pieces I need into one external client side rendering file so I only need to maintain one file for my list.

When we create a new item in the list there are some csr things I want to do on the **NewForm** when I render it, and I mostly have the CSR working for that. Upon save, there I have a custom `PreSaveAction` that creates some other list items and modifies the user input on the page.

When editing an existing item, there are some different things I want to do with the colums and I have the csr doing that correctly. I also want to have a custom `PreSaveAction`, but this time it needs to just updated the other list items it created on the new form.

Basically I control for New vs Edit in the csr like this

```
customContext.Templates.Fields = {
    'SpecialColum': { "NewForm": NewFormRender,
                      "EditForm": EditRenderFunction}
}
```

And that knows which form we're on because that is how it was designed to function.

I see that `ctx.BaseViewID` is a value of either `NewForm` or `EditForm`. But by the time I get to my custom PreSaveAction the ctx is long gone.

How do I pass the context BaseViewID to my PreSaveAction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that you did not modify the default webpart on the NewForm and EditForm webpages, then you should be able to access a global JS object named **WPQ2FormCtx**. This object is loaded before the CSR is executed. The CSR is actually using the contents of this object for things like populating the input fields with values on the EditForm webpage, etc.

So, what you need to do inside the `PreSaveAction` function is the following:

```
function PreSaveAction() {
    if (WPQ2FormCtx.FormControlMode === 3) {

        // execute code for NewForm page here

    } else if (WPQ2FormCtx.FormControlMode === 2) {

        // execute code for EditForm page here

    }
}
```

Personally, I suggest you keep your JS files separate because they will be shorter so they will load and execute faster. Also, nobody can guarantee you 100% that the **WPQ2FormCtx** object will not become **WPQ3FormCtx**, although it should not if nobody is messing with the web parts.

---

The way I approached something similar in the past was to create a variable on my global object (I always use only one global variable which is an object and to which I attach functions and other objects) and then set this variable inside the function used for the CSR of the first field in the form.

For example, I would do this:

```
// My global object.
var myGlobalObject = {...};

// CSR functions here.
myGlobalObject.NewFormRender = function NewFormRender(ctx) {
    myGlobalObject.baseViewID = ctx.BaseViewID;

    // more code here...
};

// more code here...

function PreSaveAction() {
    if (myGlobalObject.baseViewID === 'NewForm') {

        // execute code for NewForm page here...

    } else if (myGlobalObject.baseViewID === 'EditForm') {

        // execute code for EditForm page here...

    }
}
```

Note that the **NewFormRender** function above is the one you used for your **SpecialColum** field. You only need to do this in one of your custom rendering functions.

Comment: I like your second approach, but that means I would need to add that setting at the beginning of each of my custom render functions, right?

Comment: Nope, not each of your custom render functions. Just one of them because the ctx.BaseViewID variable will give you the same value, so it is redundant to do the same thing in all your render functions. Test it and you will see what I mean. :)

Comment: note that ``var myGlobalObject`` is not going into the global scope if this is declared inside a (CSR) function ... ``window.myGlobalObject = window.myGlobalObject || {}`` is the proper assignment.. also note that MDS can play tricks on you, since it does some garbage collection, and will destroy your objects if you are not properly declaring CSR initialisations (use the boiler plate code the [Cisar Chrome Extension](http://365csi.nl/cisar) gives you)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Fair points. I hope the readers are aware of the assumptions that I have made there: 1) the above code goes into a JS file as it is, namely the `myGlobalObject` variable is not declared inside any function; 2) people using MDS can look up articles on how to overcome it when applying their own CSR customisations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the Scope for the PreSaveAction with

```
function PreSaveAction(){
   var baseviewId=this;

}.bind(ctx.BaseViewId);
```

But easier might be to just whack it in the global scope
*people who say the global scope is evil, don't understand JavaScript*

```
window.MYBaseViewID = ctx.BaseViewID;
```

Comment: Where would I put that line of code to add it to the global scope?

Comment: Anywhere when ctx is available. Note that is the same concept as Mihail global object, he just wraps it in an extra container, handy when you have more to store, not required for a single variable.. global scope is global scope.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem. ctx isn't available everywhere. And there doesn't seem to be a place in the execution of the csr that always happens AND has ctx defined. Other than to make sure to add it to any and every custom render functions.